# Rounding price issue - Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, price

Magento 2.3.3 is behaving weird.

I have sample products. All have the same base price 0.30 €, tax is 19% VAT

But when my clients order the prices in the same order are sometimes 0.36 €, sometimes 0.35 €

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this? That is super strange.

I would be very thankful for any help on this.

Best regards

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look into tax calculation:
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/tax/tax-settings-general.html

I suppose you use *Tax Calculation Method Based On* **Total**? In that case 3x0,30=0,90 (netto) and you get a tax of 0,17 for Germany. Magento have no other option to distribute the tax: 0,06+0,06+0,05=0,17.

[image: Tax calculation based on Total]

If you change it to **Row Total**, refresh the Cache **AND** Update the shopping cart you see expected result:
[image: Tax calculation based on Row Total]

I test is with MG 2.3.5-p2 and 16% tax.

Mario

Comment: Dear Mario, ahhh. Sure. That makes so much sense. So I have changed the same to unit price now and suppose that will solve the problem. Thank you so much for the hint!!

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem. Price calculation per subtotal or unit price create the same behavior

Comment: Ben, I update my answer with a detailed example.

Comment: Dear @Mario, I changed it to Row Total as I thought this must bring the change, but cleaning the Cache, Static Files (I am in developer mode with the test instance) and cleaning the browser cache and updating the cart does not bring the expected result. Do I possibly have to deploy the instance as well?

Comment: I don't perform additional steps, I'm always in developer mode. First, you should ensure you are working in the right section of the settings. You can switch **Catalog Prices** to verify the effect. Second, you should check closer **Scope**s for overwriting your settings. Third, if you use a complex external skin, you should switch back to Luna. Sometimes skins can change the behavior.

Comment: Ok. I am officially stupid. What happend was, that the setting was changed in Default Config as well as in Main Website. So changing the setting to the correct Scope helped.